# Permission denied after creating django app inside docker container

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

So I am following [this](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/#static-files) tutorial and have gotten all the way to the 'media' section and when I run the command:

`docker-compose exec web python manage.py startapp upload`

it all works fine but when I open the newly created views.py file and edit and try to save I get a permission denied error. I can open the file as root and edit it but now thru my Atom code editor. I don't know where I am going wrong can someone help me? Here's my code:

Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .

# copy project
COPY . .

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=hello_django
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=hello_django
      - POSTGRES_DB=hello_django_dev

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

# python manage.py flush --no-input
# python manage.py migrate

exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to issue `chmod 777 -R` in the folder where it is located.

Comment: Ok so I opened my terminal ran chmod 777 -R uploads (the app folder) and it works. Should I add this command in my Dockerfile to avoid this issue? Why is it doing that in the first place. I'm trying to learn best practices

Comment: by default the image you are basing has some default users (just don't know in your case) but for postgres for example.. it has postgres user.. to answer your question.. it depends in your case.. but the safest would be running ```chown``` on the folder based on the user..